# I need to know if my destructor deletes the correct pointers

Tags: c++, oop, pointers

I was creating a linked list data structure, and it has alot of methods but I want to ask about my Destructor mainly, I declare three private pointers (curr, tail and head) and I set them to null in the constructor. Is what I am doing in the destructor correct or not?

```
template<typename T>
class LinkedList{
private:
    typedef struct ListNode{
        T val;
        size_t index;
        ListNode* next;
        ListNode() : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
        ListNode(T x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
    }* nodePtr;

    nodePtr head;
    nodePtr curr;
    nodePtr tail;
    size_t length = 0;

public:
//Constructor.
    LinkedList() : head{nullptr}, curr{nullptr}, tail{nullptr} {}

{.....methods....}

//Destructor.
    ~LinkedList(){
        delete head;
        delete curr;
        delete tail;
    }
};
```

I also have another question on a Push method that pushes a new node to the list, and to do so I create a temporary nodePtr in it called new_node holding the arguments passed in the Push function. Do I have to delete the new_node pointer before the ending of the scope?

```
void push(T val){
        if(head){
            nodePtr new_node = new ListNode(val);
            curr = head;

            while(curr->next){
                curr = curr->next;
            }

            curr->next = new_node;
            tail = new_node;
```

**do I have to delete the new_node here?**

```
        }
        else head = new ListNode(val);
        length++;
    }
```

Comment: What if you called push() 100 times?  Wouldn't that invoke 100 calls to `new`?  How could 3 calls to `delete` remove the memory for all of those nodes you allocated?

Comment: You need to iterate through your list freeing each node allocated.

Comment: Also what happens if curr, head and tail point to the same location?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie so I should delete the new_node in the push method if I understood you correctly, and in the destructor i should iterate and delete all nodes?

Comment: No, you do not delete in push ever. The point was if you allocated 100 nodes using 100 calls to new how would 3 total calls to delete free all 100. The answer is it would not. As I said in a previous comment you need to iterate over every node and free each node.

Comment: @SwaggyP *so I should delete the new_node in the push method* -- Why would you delete a node you just created for the list?  The destructor for the list is when it's time to destroy everything.

Comment: The rule is very simple: if something is created using `new`, it has to be destroyed using `delete`. The End. So, you need to implement whatever logic that's necessary to do that.

Comment: Okay got it, thanks to everyone